# React Native Android App crash: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x706297bfc4 in tid 1024 (mqt_js)

Tags: android, react-native

When I try to run my app on a physical Android device app gets crashes immediately on the start and this error message show on Logcat:

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x706297bfc4 in tid 1024 (mqt_js), pid 745

but when I run it on my emulator app is works fine. why I'm getting this issue?

Version:

react-native: 0.64.2 react: 16.11.0

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? We are currently having the same issue where I work.

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26930#issuecomment-591673281 
 
My issue was resolved by following this solution.